# Boton cambia a otro storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hace poco habia creado un viewcontroller para login y signUp cada pantalla con su respectivo boton para ir a home (homeViewController), sin embargo, tuve que cambiarlo para que dichas pantallas fuesen un modal y ahora los botones ya no cambian a la pantalla home. Ayuda. Anexo codigo e imagen.

```
 @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
          
    let mainStoreboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Menu", bundle: nil)
    let DVC = mainStoreboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as!
    HomeViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DVC, animated: true)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
  
}
```

[image: En la imagen esta el modal login, pero el boton going to continue ya no cambia a mi pantalla home]

Muchas gracias por prestar su ayuda amigos.

Comment: creo o me imagino que sera por el navigationController, verifica que no sea nil, ademas creo que si haces present en esos views tendrás que agregar el navigation para que puedas hacer push, de lo contrario solo presents.

Comment: De tanto intentar encontre la forma, aun asi muchas gracias amigo por tu aporte. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para los compañeros que presenten un problema similar les comparto la solución, recuerden solo aplica para cuando quieres cambiar de viewcontroller y/o storyboard desde un modal, con código.
solamente deben acompañar el codigo compartido con el siguiente

```
 view.window?.rootViewController = DVC
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

es decir quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Menu", bundle: nil)
    if let DVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController") as?
        StartViewController {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DVC, animated: true)
        
        view.window?.rootViewController = DVC
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: no, debes de usar el rootviewcontroller para cambiar de pantallas o transiciones, valida que el navigationController no sea nill.